# MVC 5 with Ninject and EF Core, Context throws exception after one query

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-core, ninject, .net-4.6.1

I am trying to use EF Core in our ASP.Net MVC 5 web application using Framework 4.6.1. We are using Ninject for dependency injection. I am injecting the Context in the DAL layer. I am successful a performing a single query but the context throws the following exception when the next query is run

> No database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A
>   provider can be configured by overriding the DbContext.OnConfiguring
>   method or by using AddDbContext on the application service provider.
>   If AddDbContext is used, then  also ensure that your DbContext type
>   accepts a DbContextOptions  object in its constructor and
>   passes it to the base constructor for DbContext.

I have seen this error before but I am not really sure how it applies in my situation. What is it about my setup that is causing this error to be thrown? Here is some code:

The Controller:

```
public ActionResult GetEnrollmentWorkflows()
{
    var class1Entities = this._class1Service.GetAll().ToList();
    var class1EntityIds = class1Entities.Select(x => x.Class1EntityId).ToList(); // Works
    var class2Entity =
        this._class2EntityService
            .GetByClass1EntityIds(class1EntityIds).ToList(); // Fails with exception
    return PartialView("_somePartial", model);
}
```

The context binding:

```
kernel.Bind<Context.ContextTenant>().ToSelf().InTransientScope()
    .WithConstructorArgument("options",
        new DbContextOptionsBuilder<Tables.ContextTenant>()
    .UseSqlServer(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings
        [EnvironmentConsts.DbConnectionTenant].ConnectionString)
    .Options);
```

The context:

```
public ContextTenant(DbContextOptions<Tables.ContextTenant> options) : base(options)
{}

protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
}
```

The Ninject Modules:

```
public class DalModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        this.Kernel.Bind(x =>
            x.FromThisAssembly().SelectAllClasses().Join
                .FromAssemblyContaining<ISomeInterface>()
                .SelectAllInterfaces()
                .BindAllInterfaces().Configure(y => y.InTransientScope()));
    }
}



public class ServiceModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        this.Kernel?.Load(new[] { new DalModule() });
        this.Kernel.Bind(x =>
            x.FromThisAssembly().SelectAllClasses().Join
                .FromAssemblyContaining<ISomeInterface>()
                .SelectAllInterfaces()
                .BindAllInterfaces().Configure(y => y.InTransientScope()));
    }
}
```

The DAL Classes

Class1:

```
public class Class1Repository : IClass1Repository
{
    private ContextTenant ContextTenant { get; }

    public Class1Repository(ContextTenant contextTenant)
    {
        ContextTenant = contextTenant;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Class1Entity> GetAll()
    {
        return this.ContextTenant.Class1Entity.Select(x => x);
    }
}
```

Class 2:

```
public class Class2Repository : IClass2Repository
{
    private readonly ContextTenant _contextTenant;

    public Class2Repository(ContextTenant contextTenant)
    {
        _contextTenant = contextTenant;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Class2Entity> GetByClass1EntityIds(
        IEnumerable<int> class1EntityIds)
    {
        return this._contextTenant.Class2Entity.Where(x =>
            class1EntityIds.Contains(x.Class1EntityId));
    }
}
```

The Services:

```
public class Class1Service : IClass1Service
{
    private readonly IClass1Repository _class1Repository;

    public Class1Service(IClass1Repository class1Repository)
    {
        _class1Repository = class1Repository;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Class1Entity> GetAll()
    {
        return this._class1Repository.GetAll();
    }
}

public class Class2Service : IClass2Service
{
    private readonly IClass2Repository _class2Repository;

    public Class2Service(IClass2Repository class2Repository)
    {
        _class2Repository = class2Repository;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Class2Entity> GetByClass1EntityIds(
        IEnumerable<int> class1EntityIds)
    {
        return this._class2Repository.GetByClass1EntityIds(class1EntityIds);
    }
}
```

Edit:
Here is a little bit more code from the start up in case this would affect anything:

```
[assembly: WebActivatorEx.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(NinjectWebCommon), "Start")]
[assembly: WebActivatorEx.ApplicationShutdownMethod(typeof(NinjectWebCommon), "Stop")]
namespace MyApp
{
    public static class NinjectWebCommon
    {
        private static readonly Bootstrapper bootstrapper = new Bootstrapper();

        public static void Start()
        {
            DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(OnePerRequestHttpModule));
            DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(NinjectHttpModule));
            bootstrapper.Initialize(CreateKernel);
        }

        public static void Stop()
        {
            bootstrapper.ShutDown();
        }

        private static IKernel CreateKernel()
        {
            // Bind the context
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I am reading above I believe it is because you are using RequestScope. The thing is that db context will dispose after each using and because you are still in the same request, when you call it again it has been disposed, but yet it serves that same instance. Change it to Transient (or Transient equivalent with Ninject, meaning get new db context on every request) and it should fix the problem.

Comment: I just tried TransientScope and it still has the same behavior. I replaced all of the RequestScope with TransientScope.

Comment: @Thomas927 Are you 100% sure the error has not changed?

Comment: Yes, the error did not change at all; I compared the logs between today and yesterday

Comment: @Thomas927 Based on the code you have posted above, I don't see anything else wrong. I assume the code above is not your actual production code, but more/less of pseudo code.I would suggest to create a working demo on github with your error producing that we can take a look at, otherwise I don't think I can help. In any case, at the very least you will want to keep your db context on Transient vs Request, even if it is not the cause of this problem.

Comment: The above is basically the same code, just changed the names. I have updated the question with a little more code in case there is something in the ninject start up that is causing this error to be thrown. I will probably try to repro this and will provide a link if I do.

Comment: @Thomas927 the context binding says request scope, maybe you missed it during testing?

Comment: I did not change the original code that I put in the question. I just changed it on my dev machine and tested. Are you seeing something in the code I added in the edit that would limit to RequestScope? I only added the code for NinjectWebCommon

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178711/discussion-between-bojan-and-thomas927).

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems in the past that sometimes could be solved by changing

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
}
```

In

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    if (optionsBuilder.IsConfigured == false)
    { 
        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
    }
}
```

Comment: I kind-of-sort-of confirmed that this does not make a difference. The other application that I am working on also suffers from this issue. It was created only 6 months ago so there is not a lot of legacy stuff going on. From what I remember I think I removed that check because the break point placed there was never being hit so having an override fore this method did not make sense. I left it there just in case the final solution needed that override.